# 2.8 inch tft LCD displays / Max Brightness / Startup White Screen / mirror text for Head Up Display Usage

Tags: arduino-uno

hi does anyone know how to

1) set Max Brightness 
2) change the start up splash screen from being white to black 
3) how to change settings so that text can be mirrored so when display is reflected into mirror or glass window the text reflects onto the mirror / glass so that it is readable

The code from the sketch may answer some of your tecnical question re the environment i am working with

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h> // Hardware-specific library

#define LCD_CS A3 // Chip Select goes to Analog 3
#define LCD_CD A2 // Command/Data goes to Analog 2
#define LCD_WR A1 // LCD Write goes to Analog 1
#define LCD_RD A0 // LCD Read goes to Analog 0
```

Comment: 1. can be done w/hjardware usually, PWM'ing the backlight. 2 is just whatever the demo code does, there's no std splash screen. 3. you'll have to modify the gfx lib or use a custom font.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) set Max Brightness

You set the brightness of the backlight (usually) using PWM.

> 2) change the start up splash screen from being white to black

That's not a splash screen. That's just the back light being on before the screen is initialised. Just don't turn on the back light until you need it.

> 3) how to change settings so that text can be mirrored so when display is reflected into mirror or glass window the text reflects onto the mirror / glass so that it is readable

Either do it in software (tricky) or look at the MADCTL (many have it called that) register in the datasheet.  The library probably won't support it, but it's part of how it deals with display rotation, so you could examine that function and compare it with what's in the datasheet (hint: 180° rotation is actually flipping both the X and Y axis).

Comment: Thanks for the answers above. Sorry this is all very new to me

Comment: Thanks for the answers above. Sorry I dont have an electronics / component background please excuse the nievety.

Answer 1 above, 

what is PWM and where do i find it and how do i use it to achieve point 1 objective

Answer 2 Above 

So how do i turn offf the backlight as the uit backlight lights up as soon as power is connected even when the LCD is not connected to the processor, so i assume its not using the code to initally turn the back light on given there is no arduio processing any code yet the backlight is on

Answer 3

Where do i find the MADCTL  in order to alter it

Comment: Majenco i really do appreicate your assistance so far. I was hoping t find a graphics driiver option so i could code the reverse / mirror flip. I am looking to add an gyro to the unit so that if the unit is flipped so it faces driver not windscreen  (opposite to  default position the code detects this from gyro output & then changes the aspect of code being displayed so its readable by driver. Same logic to be applied if the driver wants it placed upside down form the default position so that power connector was on left side not right side (allowing for left / right hand drive)

Comment: PWM: Pulse Width Modulation. Involves turning an output on and off very rapidly with varying ratios of on-to-off times to simulate an analog output. Control the pins that have `~` by them with `analogWrite()`.

Comment: How you control the back light depends on what shield you are using.

Comment: For MADCTL read the datasheet for the TFT screen on your chosen shield.

Comment: the 2.8 tft lcd qr4 5265s01 g3/2 TP28017

Comment: This one? https://www.adafruit.com/product/1651